# return index of 2d array

Tags: c++, arrays

how to return index of all elements in a 2d array which are bigger than 0? I am going to use c++.

```
int distances[2][3]={{0,8,0},{0,4,0}};

for(int i=0; i<2; i++){
    for(int j=0; j<3; j++){
    if(distances[i][j] > 1){
         //row=i/3;
         //columns=i%3;
         cout << distances[i][j] << " " << endl;          //value
```

thanks in advance

Comment: is `vector of vector` a choice for you?

Comment: you can return only one value, either return struct, or array, or use pass by reference/address

Comment: Well, `distances[i][j] > 0` for starters ...

Comment: You could return a collection of pairs (`vector<pair<int,int> >`), with each entry in your vector being the index into the array in 2d. Would need modification if you have more than 2d, mind.

Answer (score 1):

Write a function and have it return a vector of pairs:

```
std::vector<std::pair<size_t,size_t>> filter();
```

Answer (score 0):

The index is (i,j) for all values where distances[i][j] > 0.

If you want to return it e.g. from a function, you could make a class, map, vector, struct etc.

```
struct pair {
    int i
    int j
};
```

(...)

```
pair p;
p.i = i;
p.j = j;
return p;
```

Comment: Why reinvent `std::pair`?